# g_main_loop, fork, threads

Tags: c, multithreading, exec, fork, glib

I believe this is a simple question but I can't find the necessary answer that I need in the internet so far.

I have a pseudo code as follows in my mind:

```
main() {
    loop = g_main_loop;

    main_loop_callback(keyboard_cb, keyboard input);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
}
```

my callback function is going to be like this:

```
keyboard_cb {
    start_process(./rtsp_server "port / mountPoint / input");
}
```

and the process I want to start is something like this:

```
main {
    loop = g_main_loop;

    rtsp_server(port, mountPoint, input);

    g_main_loop_run(loop);
}
```

I already have a rtsp server code that works perfectly in the way that I want. However, I am unsure how to call this program from another `C` program. I first wanted to use `fork` however, it writes in the reference manual that `g_main_loop` and `fork` are not compatible and I should use `exec()`.

Is this doable with exec()?

Would `g_main_loops` get confused with each other since they all use the default context?

Considering that I may create some arbitrary number of rtsp_servers and each `rtsp_server` has its own `g_main_loop`, would `exec()` get stucked after I create my first server? Would I need a thread inside the `keyboard_cb` so that it wouldn't get stuck?

Comment: I think fork/exec is fine as long as you don't use the event loop between `fork()` and `exec()`.. the docs seem to be saying that you must exit or exec (from the child process) *after forking*, without returning to mainloop -- not that you should use `exec()` instead of `fork()`.

Comment: @Dmitri I will try that tomorrow and report the outcomes.

Comment: @Dmitri I have tried what you suggested but it doesn't work as I want it to.